# Informação não chega no atributo value

Tags: php, html, mvc, atributos, value

A informação que pego no model usuario (método getTimeLine) chega até o homeController, mas não chega na homeView no input type hidden no atributo value.

```
public function perfil($id) {
    $dados = array();

    $p = new posts();

    if(isset($_POST['msg']) && !empty($_POST['msg'])) {

        $msg = addslashes($_POST['msg']);
        $time_line = addslashes($_POST['time_line']);
        $p->inserirPost($msg, $time_line);
    }

    $u = new usuarios($id);
    $dados['nome'] = $u->getNome();
    $dados['localizacao'] = $u->getLocalizacao();
    $dados['avatar'] = $u->getAvatar();
    $dados['feed'] = $u->getFeed();
    $dados['time_line'] = $p->getTimeLine();


    $this->loadTemplate('home', $dados);
}
```

[image: Var_dump mostra que o valor esta preenchido na variável time_line.]

```html
<!-- Formulario -->
<div class="well">
 <h4 class="text-center">Redactar un nuevo Tweet</h4>
 <form method="POST" class="form-group">
  <textarea name="msg" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea><br/>

  <input type="hidden" name="time_line" value="<?php echo $time_line; ?>">

  <input type="submit" value="Twittear" class="btn btn-primary" />
 </form>
</div>
<!-- End formulario -->
```

[image: Atributo value vazio.]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o codigo aqui e as imagens, é mais simples do que pedir que alguém entre outro local para verificar seu erro

Comment: A primeira imagem é saida de que variável ?

Comment: A primeira imagem é um var_dump do array $dados que esta no controller, nesse array tem tudo o que eu preciso mostrar na view. A segunda imagem mostra o código fonte da view, onde tudo o que está em $dados é impresso, menos a variável time_line no input hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque a função **getTimeLine** que você tem por essa:

```
public function getTimeLine($id){

    $sql = "SELECT time_line FROM posts WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($query->rowCount() > 0){

        $row = $query->fetch();

        return $row['time_line'];
    }
}
```

Agora toda vez que você chamar a função **getTimeLine** você passa a ID do POST (creio que é do post que você pega na query) diretamente na função:

```
$this->getTimeLine(12345);
```

Comment: Consegui, descobri o problema. Foi quase isso, Alisson. Tenho uma coluna na tabela posts que se chama id_usuario, que sempre é igual a coluna id da tabela de usuarios. O problema e estava na query, com a correção, apareceram outros probleminhas, que foram solucionados.

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar um select na tabela, pois o que você está fazendo não tem sentido, você está dando echo em praticamente nada, pois não tem time_line definida como variável entende, portante tente um exemplo como este abaixo

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM time_line";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result); 
    $dados = = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>

<input type="hidden" name="time_line"  value="<?php echo $dados['time_line']; ?>" >
```

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de mostrar a foto da minha query. Vou publica-la agora.

Comment: Então você terá que colocar essa  query na página do formulário e pegar o value da forma que indiquei, pois dando somente echo na variável não dará certo

Comment: O que é confuso para mim, é porque eu pude até agora trazer outras informaçoes como: avatar, localização, nome e somente essa variável não quer aparecer.

Comment: Tentou fazer como eu falei ? indique o erro que consta quando faz desta forma por favor... Tire do hidden e coloque text e se aparecer erro dentro do hidden você irá saber o que esta acontencendo